# how can i utilize the power of CLUSTER ENVIRONMENT for my thread pool that is dealing with I/O bound jobs?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, hazelcast

I have developed a JAVA based server having a Thread Pool that is dynamically growing with respect to client request rate.This strategy is known as FBOS(Frequency Based Optimization Strategy) [FBOS for Thread pool System](http://www.thenucleuspak.org.pk/nucleus/AdminArea/Accepted_papers/%5B11%5D%20MS-952%20F%20Bahadur.pdf).

For example if request rate is 5 requests per second then my thread pool will have 5 threads to service client's requests. The client requests are I/O bound jobs of 1 seconds.i.e. each request is a runnable java object that have a sleep() method to simulate I/O operation.

If client request rate is 10 requests per second then my thread pool will have 10 threads inside in it to process clients. Each Thread have an internal timer object that is activated when its corresponding thread is idle and when its idle time becomes 5 seconds the timer will delete its corresponding thread from the Thread Pool to dynamically shrink the Thread Pool.

My strategy is working well for short I/O intensities.My server is working nicely for small request rate but for large request rate my Thread pool have large number of threads inside it. For example if request rate is 100 request per second then my Thread Pool will have 100 threads inside it.

Now I have 3 questions in my mind

(1) Can i face memory leaks using this strategy, for large request rate?

(2) Can OS or JVM face excessive Thread management overhead on large request rate that will slow down the system

(3) Last and very important question is that ,I am very curious to implement my thread Pool in a clustered environment(I am DUMMY in clustering).

I just want to take advice from all of you that how a clustering environment can give me more benefit in the scenario of Frequency Based Thread Pool for I/O bound jobs only. That is can a clustering environment give me benefit of using memories of other systems(nodes)?

Comment: If it's truly IO-bound, then won't two simultaneous requests be served each at half speed? If each request is just blocking while waiting for a remote system to reply, that's not really IO-bound.

Comment: Suppose each request is an http request demanding for a single page and page takes 1 second to fetch and send then FBOS server is responsible to create as much threads on the server side as request rate and each thread will take 1 second to fetch the page and send it to client. What did u meant by "Not really I/o Bound". I am actually more interesred in my 3rd question marko

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to use is a cached thread pool, see `Executors` I suggest you try this first.  This will create the number of threads to need at once.  For an IO bound request, a single machine can easily expand to 1000s of threads without needing an additional server.

> Can i face memory leaks using this strategy, for large request rate?

No, 100 per second is not particularly high. If you are talking over 10,000 per second, you might have a problem (or need another server)

> Can OS or JVM face excessive Thread management overhead on large request rate that will slow down the system

Yes, my rule of thumb is that 10,000 threads wastes about 1 cpu in overhead.

> Last and very important question is that ,I am very curious to implement my thread Pool in a clustered environment(I am DUMMY in clustering).

Given you look to be using up to 1% of one machine, I wouldn't worry about using multiple machines to do the IO.  Most likely you want to process the results, but without more information you couldn't say whether more machines would help or not.

> can a clustering environment give me benefit of using memories of other systems(nodes)?

It can help if you need it or it can add complexity you don't need if you don't need it.

I suggest you start with a real problem and look for a solution to solve it, rather than start with a cool solution and try to find a problem for it to solve.

Comment: very helpful reply: Peter i want to ask another thing, i want to distribute my Thread Pool into 2 parts one Thread Pool deals with I/O Bound requests and another Thread Pool deals with CPU-Bound requests and i submit each request to its corresponding Thread Pool. I want both of these Thread Pools on different machines in a DSM environment. Am i right if i build this system? i.e. Two Thread Pools in DSM for 2 different types of requests?

Comment: @user3671023 You can do this, but I would only do so if there is a good reason. Without more information, I would have to assume that you just want to try it out, but I suspect it won't help you.  On the other hand if you have have more CPU tasks than you have CPUs, running the CPU intensive tasks across two machine might help.

Comment: Peter no doubt that I am trying it out because i am a research student. i have to create an agent based Thread Pool System for DSM but first my task is to create a simple thread Pool system distributed on two different machines one for CPU jobs one for I/O jobs.According to your suggestion my FBOS thread pool for I/O bound jobs will work  well on a single machine but how many threads should i create in Thread Pool of Cpu-Bound jobs. Is it right if i keep Thread-Pool size=(number of nodes) * number of cores per node.